# Switching arrow key mappings for wildmenu tab completion

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, wildmenu

When wanting to edit another file, I'm a big fan of typing

```
:e
```

then tab (or a few characters before) to see the wildmenu pop up.

Problem is that the way it works, arrows keys up and down go 'down' or 'up' in the hierarchy and left and right lets you navigate through file within the same hierarchy level.

This is very unintuitive for me as I would like the up and down arrows to select file and the side arrows to change hierarchical level.

I know how to remap keys in general, but I never had to remap keys specifically for one command and I'm unsure how to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by mapping the keys to behave differently when the wildmenu is visible:

```
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
cnoremap <expr> <up> wildmenumode() ? "\<left>" : "\<up>"
cnoremap <expr> <down> wildmenumode() ? "\<right>" : "\<down>"
cnoremap <expr> <left> wildmenumode() ? "\<up>" : "\<left>"
cnoremap <expr> <right> wildmenumode() ? " \<bs>\<C-Z>" : "\<right>"
```

These use an [expression mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-expression) that checks whether the wildmenu is showing with the [`wildmenumode()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#wildmenumode%28%29) function returning the altered keystroke if that it is, and returning the regular keystroke if it isn't (so that the keys still work normally when you're not using the wildmenu).

There is a slight complication in the mapping for the right arrow key, which is that it appears that the "go into subdirectory" behaviour is implemented internally as a macro that does something along the lines of `<space><bs><tab>`, but because [`'wildchar'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildchar%27) cannot be used in a macro, the `<tab>` is instead inserted literally in the command line, appearing as CTRL-I: `^I`.

I've worked around this by using [`'wildcharm'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildcharm%27) and mapping to that instead of directly to `<down>`.

To make the mappings more precise, you can also check the current contents of the command-line to make sure it's an `:e` command:

```
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
cnoremap <expr> <up> getcmdline()[:1] is 'e ' && wildmenumode() ? "\<left>" : "\<up>"
cnoremap <expr> <down> getcmdline()[:1] is 'e ' && wildmenumode() ? "\<right>" : "\<down>"
cnoremap <expr> <left> getcmdline()[:1] is 'e ' && wildmenumode() ? "\<up>" : "\<left>"
cnoremap <expr> <right> getcmdline()[:1] is 'e ' && wildmenumode() ? " \<bs>\<C-Z>" : "\<right>"
```

If you also need the mappings to work for the other variants of the `:e` command: `:ed`, `:edi`, and `:edit`, you can instead use a regular expression:

```
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
let edit_re = 'e\%[dit] '
cnoremap <expr> <up> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<left>" : "\<up>"
cnoremap <expr> <down> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<right>" : "\<down>"
cnoremap <expr> <left> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? "\<up>" : "\<left>"
cnoremap <expr> <right> getcmdline() =~# edit_re && wildmenumode() ? " \<bs>\<C-Z>" : "\<right>"
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way of checking whether the `wildmenu` is completing filenames ([`complete_info()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#complete_info%28%29) only appears to work for insert mode completion, and I couldn't find a similar function for command-line completion), so there doesn't appear to be a better method of applying it to *all* filename wildmenu completions.

If you need this, you will have either use the original version which applies regardless of what the wildmenu is completing, or use a more complicated regular expression to check for all the commands where you need the mappings to be in effect.

Comment: This works like a charm for navigating between files in the same level, but I'm not able to properly navigate to a subdirectory. It prints ^I in the command line after pressing right arrow and pressing tab again doesn't register the directory change as it shows me the options of the same level.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @Delhirio See my most recent edit for an explanation and solution. It should now work like a (wild)charm for navigating to subdirectories, too!

Comment: It does seems to work flawlessly now! Thank you!

Comment: @Delhirio Glad I could help!

Comment: This had been driving me crazy for years until I finally googled around for it and found your solution. Works perfectly, thanks so much! Lots of frustration saved.

Comment: @Vlad-ȘtefanHarbuz Glad I could help!

Comment: why is this `set wildcharm=<C-Z>` necessary?

Comment: @alexzander The mapping for the right-arrow doesn't work without it. See the two paragraphs beginning `There is a slight complication[...]`

Comment: @Rich these mappings are weird. when using them i get those dots in the command-line [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwtHh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwtHh.png) i get 3 dots (`...`) every time i press `up` or `down`, but when using `tab` or `s-tab` the dots dont appear anymore.

Comment: @alexzander That's odd. Do you see the same problem if you start Vim with `vim --clean` and enter the mappings manually? Were you planning to use the mappings only for `:e` like Delhiro? I ask because your screenshot appears to show you using them for the `:!` command. If I type `:!<tab>` _without_ the mappings installed I get three dots while Vim looks for completions, but it very quickly resolves them into the first suggestion. If you wait a bit after pressing `up` do the dots go away for you?

Comment: its happening also without the bang

Comment: @alexzander What about my other questions?

Comment: This is what the default configuration should be. In what world should Left/Right arrow keys be used to go up and down a list?!